# Object not sending properly from angular to express

Tags: angular, express

I'm trying to send some data from angular to express. I created `auth.service` and created a function in which it posts the data from the input fields to my express server. I have a feeling it's specifically this line that's breaking it, but I don't know why or if I'm even correct `return this.http.post<any>(this._registerUrl, user);`

because if I log `user` before that line, it's still the actual users object. If I log `req.body` on the POST request on my Express server, it logs `{}`. The other reason I believe it's that line only is because doing a post request with Postman creates the account correctly and has the user object in `req.body`

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

    private _registerUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/register';
    private _loginUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/login';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    registerUser(user) {
        console.log(user)
        return this.http.post<any>(this._registerUrl, user);
    }

    loginUser(user) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, user);
    }

}
```

**register.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-register',
    templateUrl: './register.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

    registerUserData = {}

    constructor(private _auth: AuthService) { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    registerUser() {

        this._auth.registerUser(this.registerUserData)
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    console.log('_auth.registerUser', res)
                },
                err => console.log(err)
        )

    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have created a new application and still seem to be having troubles with a pretty simple setup. With this setup, I have three console.logs. The first two logs, log the user object correctly, but the third one logs a blank body. The POST request works because I bundled a test string with it like so (this is the post request function)

```
res.send({
    body: req.body,
    test: 'foobar'
});
```

the third console.log gets this:

```
{
    body: {},
    test: "foobar"
}
```

When I send something, it shows one POST request, with the payload of `{username: "ff", password: "ff"}` (what I put) with a status of 200.

This is what I have now:

**register.component.html**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.username" name="username" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.password" name="password" type="password">
    </div>
    <button (click)="registerUser()" type="button">Register</button>
</form>
```

**register.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-register',
    templateUrl: './register.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

    registerUserData = {}
    constructor(private _auth: AuthService) { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    registerUser() {
        console.log('1', this.registerUserData)
        this._auth.registerUser(this.registerUserData)
            .subscribe(
                res => console.log('3', res),
                err => console.log('3 err', err)
            )
    }

}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private _registerUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/register'

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    registerUser(user) {
        console.log('2', user);
        return this.http.post<any>(this._registerUrl, user);
    }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        RegisterComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    providers: [AuthService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**UPDATE 2:** Using Postman and having the header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while also using `x-www-form-urlencoded` as the body with the key username set, this returns the correct response with the username. Though if I switch the body in postman to Raw and use JSON(application/json) option, and put an object with a key of username in the body, it *doesn't* return the correct response. So maybe it has something to do with how my cors is set up in my express server?

In my Express server I have required cors and after I start my express server I have `app.use(cors())` as I don't have any options set. Maybe this is a headers issue?

Comment: Did you check browser tools and see what your service is actually sending e.g. use Chrome devtools.

Comment: have you subscribed to the request ? also post how you are using the post method

Comment: @CuriousMind - I have just now, it showed it was pending. How can I fix this?

Comment: If it is showing pending in DevTools, can you check what data is being sent along with the request OR is it empty?

Comment: @CuriousMind - I've updated my post with the relevant information.